# Different angular routing for different ionic platforms

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I need to use two different angular routes for two different ionic platforms.

```
 const routes_a: Routes = [
  ...
 ]
 const routes_b: Routes = [
  ...
 ]
 @NgModule({
   imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes_a)],
   exports: [RouterModule]
 })
 export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

So what I need is that if my Ionic App has platform 'cordova', it should use routes_a in the Router Module and otherwise route_b. How can I achieve this?